# C: segfault on merge sort only on large files

Tags: c, sorting, memory, segmentation-fault, mergesort

The following code sorts an array of words, working on small arrays, and segfaulting on large ones (>400000 words, though I haven't found a limit). It is being called by a program that passes it an array of words (read from a file) to be sorted and tests its success:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

#include "csort.h"
#include "sort.h"

// array points to array of pointers to strings, count is number of entries in array

void sortC(char** array, unsigned int count){
  array = merge_sort(array, count);
  // testing:
  /*for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
    printf("%s ", array[i]);
    }*/
}

char** merge_sort(char** array, int count){
  if (count <= 1) return array;
  else {
    int lcount = 0;
    int rcount = 0;
    int middle = count/2;
    lcount = middle;
    char* left[lcount];
    subArray(array, left, 0, middle);
    rcount = count-middle;
    char* right[rcount];
    subArray(array, right, middle, count);
    return merge(merge_sort(left, lcount), merge_sort(right, rcount), array, 0, lcount, rcount);
  }
}

void subArray(char** array, char** subarray, int start, int end){
  int ai; // index in original array
  int si; // index in subarray
  for (ai = start, si = 0; ai < end; ai++, si++){
    subarray[si] = array[ai];
  }
}

char** merge(char** left, char** right, char** output, int oi, int lcount, int rcount){
  if (lcount > 0 && rcount > 0){
    int lmin = findMinimum(left, lcount);
    int rmin = findMinimum(right, rcount);
    if (strcmp(left[lmin], right[rmin]) < 0){
      output[oi] = left[lmin];
      removeFromArray(left, lmin, lcount);
      lcount--;
    }
    else {
      output[oi] = right[rmin];
      removeFromArray(right, rmin, rcount);
      rcount--;
    }
  }
  else if (lcount == 0) {
    if (rcount == 1) {
      output[oi] = right[0];
      return output;
    } else {
      int rmin = findMinimum(right, rcount);
      output[oi] = right[rmin];
      removeFromArray(right, rmin, rcount);
      rcount--;
    }
  }
  else if (rcount == 0) {
    if (lcount == 1) {
      output[oi] = left[0];
      return output;
    } else {
      int lmin = findMinimum(left, lcount);
      output[oi] = left[lmin];
      removeFromArray(left, lmin, lcount);
      lcount--;
    }
  }
  return merge(left, right, output, ++oi, lcount, rcount);
}

int findMinimum(char** array, int count){
  char* minvalue = array[0];
  char* currentvalue = minvalue;
  int minindex = 0;
  for (int i = 1; i < count; i++){
    currentvalue = array[i];
    if (strcmp(currentvalue, minvalue) < 0){
      minvalue = currentvalue;
      minindex = i;
    }
  }
  return minindex;
}

void removeFromArray(char** array, int index, int count){
  // removes specified index from an array
  for (int i = index; i < count; i++){
    if (i+1 == count){
      array[i] = 0; // this entry will be gone when count decrements
    } else {
      array[i] = array[i+1];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific question here? Have you run it in the debugger to see where it's segfaulting?

Comment: (gdb) run
Enter File Name: kjvbible.txt
790691 words were read.

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x08048a1d in merge (left=0xff518910, right=0xff5006e0, output=0xff530bd0, oi=35226, lcount=7036, rcount=7157) at csort.c:48
/home/elijah_houle/cs261/sort/csort.c:48:1185:beg:0x8048a1d

Comment: Why is it segfaulting? A backtrace is not helpful as it just shows "merge()" being called thousands of times.

Comment: The "omly when N is very large" makes this sound like your problem is during memory allocation. Are you sure that everything is working fine to that point, all mallocs returned non null, etc?

Comment: I would suggest recompiling with debugging symbols ( `-g` ) to find out exactly where you are having a problem.

Answer (score 2):

If there's no bug on your code then the problem might be how you are storing the data. Do you use `malloc()` to allocate the array to store your data or are you declaring an array that is *big enough*?

For large data sets you must use `malloc()`, which will allocate space on the HEAP instead of the stack. **The stack has a limited space**. This would explain why with smaller data your program works and with bigger data sets it crashes.

Also one very important point is that you are using recursion: merge() calling merge(). Too many recursive calls could lead to a stack overflow (segfault).

Comment: You would think he'd get a `Stack Overflow` error if that were the case. (Though he might be, and not telling us since the question is fairly short on details.).

Comment: @Robin Green: The return value, you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a stack overflow, you are allocating automatic arrays of thousands if items in each invocation, and then recursing.

These lines, to be specific:

```
char* left[lcount];
```

and

```
char* right[rcount];
```

For the values in your comment, where count == 7157, this would be quite costly in terms of stack space.

Consider either using `malloc()` for these, or figure out a way to represent a sub-array without requiring new memory.